# Unique solution of differential equations $x^{ \prime\prime}=f(t)x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$Problem$:  Let $0<c_1<f(t)<c_2$ show that there is a unique solution bounded in $[0, \infty)$ of the equation:

$$x^{ \prime\prime}=f(t)x$$ and this solution $x(t)\to 0$, where $t\to \infty$.

Can anybody help me please? Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: $x=0$ is a solution and satisfies your requirements, except for uniqueness. For that, you need initial conditions.